# Android: How can I achieve/draw an arrow and put a text on top of it using Canvas/Paint?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to achieve the below picture (i made it via excel).

[image]

Here are the requirements:

1. arrow down shape
2. "GOAL" text on top of it
3. tip of the arrow should be pointed on the given x,y
4. transparent effect (i think its setAlpha(0..255))
5. gradient effect (top to bottom)
6. emboss effect (optional)
7. lighting effect (optional)

Any guidance is appreciated.
*i don't have idea on how to draw. please guide us via code snippets example.

**UPDATES**
I just need small icon.

Comment: Want you to be the drawn result scaleable? So look the same when scaled from `100x100` to `200x200`? Or should be anything variable (besides the text)? If not then drawing is an overkill and I would stick to images instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to go for nine patch image. set backgrond of textview is "nineparch image". and setyour text view at x,y using absolute layout.

Nine patch is available here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

it may help you.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, need to have an existing image to use that tool isn't? Is it possible to create the image in the program using canvas/paint?

Comment: @eros: you can take bytton or image button with text "goal" and use ninepatch image of arrow as background of that button